# Guice private parent Module expose binding to child modules

Tags: guice

I have following Guice private module dependency tree:

```java
public class FooModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      install(new BarModule());
      bind(Person.class);
      expose(Person.class);
    }
}

public class BarModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      install(new LifeImplModule());
      bind(Animal.class);
      expose(Animal.class);
    }
}

public class LifeImplModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Life.class).toInstance(new LifeImpl());
      expose(Life.class);
    }
}

public class Animal {
    @Inject
    public Animal(Life life) {
      //
    }
}

public class Person {
    @Inject
    public Person(Life life) {
       //
    }
}
```

Now when I do `Guice.createInjector(new FooModule()).getInstance(Person.class)`  - it fails since it doesn't recognize binding for `Life.class` whereas `Guice.createInjector(new FooModule()).getInstance(Animal.class)` works since it has binding for `Life` via `BarModule`.

How do I go about solving this issue? I tried moving
`install(new LifeImplModule());` to `FooModule()` but then `Animal.class` doesn't work, while `Person.class` does.

Could anybody explain how does Guice private module work in terms of inheriting bindings? Is `install(LifeImplModule())` in `FooModule` not work for both `Person.class` and child module `BarModule()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BarModule` is a private module, any modules installed inside it won't be available externally.
That's why

```
install(new LifeImplModule());
```

doesn't grant access to `Life` binding for `FooModule`.
You can solve it by explicitly exposing `Life` from `BarModule`

```
install(new LifeImplModule());
expose(Life.class);
```